# Перемещение курсором мыши UI элемента внутри окна WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу узнать возможно ли (и если да, то как) реализовать код в XAML таким образом, чтобы можно было перемещать курсором мыши `<Border>` `1`(изображено на рисунке красной цифрой `1`) внутри `<Grid>` или `<Window>`. НЕ внутри экрана монитора, а внутри `<Window>` или `<Grid>`. Перемещаться будет **только** `<Border>` `1` внутри доступного пространства окна `<Window>`. Само собой это не должно быть новым окном.

Сейчас у меня XAML **схематично** выглядит следующим образом:

```
<Window WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent" Width="690">
    <Grid Width="690">
         <Border>...</Border> //Это <Border> 1, Visibility=Hidden/Visible по нажатию кнопки, которая находится на <Border> 2

        <Border Width="400">...</Border> //Это <Border> 2 на рисунке, основное окно программы
        
    </Grid
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: Вас спасут контролы `Adorner` и `Thumb`, штука не простая, я сам в ней неделю ковырялся и не до конца понял. Ну или вот так можно https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-enabling-drag-and-drop-on-a-user-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-5.0

Comment: Мне кажется тут уже нечто на MDI похоже, может стоит смотреть в его сторону?